# UISearchbar issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am trying to add a UISearchbar to table header view.
I have the icon in nib and have connected the outlets.

Now in viewDidLoad, I am writing 
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchbar

If i create a local var inside viewDidLoad, it shows up. But not the outlet or ivar one.

But for some reason, the UISearchbar does not get displayed in the table. 
I am not sure what the issue is. Can a UISearchbar not be set in viewDidLoad

OR is it something else?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you insert the SearchBarController or just the SearchBar object in IB? You have to choose the SearchBarController to interact with.

put in your `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` or `tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:` method:

```
MyVC *vc = [[MyVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"MyVCNibName" andBundle:nil];
[self.view presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
[vc release];
```

you can also try and add a blank UIView with red backgroundColor to your view and see if its displayed (so you would know if the nib is loaded anyway)

Comment: just the SearchBar object in MyVC.xib window

Comment: For some reason, I am wondering that my class MyVC is not loading from MyVC.xib which has the UISearchBar object. How can I ensure that? In MyVC.xib , for File's ownder, I have class set to MyVC Also hooked up the outlets. Any other things to consider?

Comment: MyVC *vc = [[MyVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"ActionChooser" bundle:nil];

Comment: Where do I specify this ? MyVC *vc = [[MyVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"ActionChooser" bundle:nil]; In which file ? In the nib file, I already have File's owner set to MyVC.

Comment: ok, then the question is, how do you actually load the view? btw. it shouldn't be @"ActionChooser" but your Nib-name e.g. @"MyVC"

Comment: 1. I do not have loadView implemented in MyVC. So, I think it is loaded from MyVC.xib 2. But I do not know why it does not consider the searchbar outlet. My view has table view implemented in code (MyVC.m) and search bar outlet.
2. Also do I need to add; MyVC *vc  = [[MyVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"ActionChooser" bundle:nil];

Comment: I think I am doing something incorrectly while connecting the xib with MyVC.m
I mean first i created MyVC.m and then manually added or rather imported MyVC.xib
Even though I have connected the outlets and all, there is something that I might be missing.
Could you point if I am doing something wrong while manually adding the xib

Comment: the question is, when does your view get loaded? in your AppDelegate because its the very first view, or is it loaded after the app has began and the user has clicked on a button or so

Comment: it gets loaded on click/select of table row item.

Comment: Also the controller class is kind of dynamically created or rather the name...What I mean is on click of diff rows in the table, diff class names are created dynamically and then the controller property is set ...In my case, this particular row gets called as initWithStyle: UITableViewGrouped...